# String or binary data would be truncated - cast decimal(18,4)

Tags: sql, sql-server

When we are consuming web services, which are giving special characters in the decimal field, while inserting into SQL server we need to do casting to decimal which is giving below-mentioned error.

I have tried to avoid special characters in the SQL that have added the condition which is to avoid special characters. Below I have given code that I tried.

```sql
select @StringVal  = (case when @StringVal like '%[^0-9.]%' then '0'
             when @StringVal like '%.%.%' then '0'
             else @StringVal 
        end)

CAST(@StringVal AS decimal(18,4))
```

> String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: Providing a [mre] is always really helpful.

Comment: Provide us the string value, that you think it has `special characters`. Also provide the statement which you get that error, the field type (if that is character field, the width of it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing this in one step using `try_convert()`:

```
select coalesce(try_convert(decimal(18, 4), @StringVal), 0)
```

`try_convert()` returns `NULL` if the value cannot be converted to a decimal.  In that case, you seem to want `0` instead.